# Get empty First name and last name for some users from Google OAuth

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

Our system using **Google Oauth** to allow a user to sign up from Google account. However, for some of the users, we can only get email and avatar but not First Name and Last Name.

The setting in Oauth Google Console having following scopes added

- email
- profile
- openid
- /auth/contacts.readonly

Using the following scope for requesting

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

The result return from API is

```
{
  "identifier": "1026834XXX",
  "webSiteURL": "",
  "profileURL": "",
  "photoURL": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/a-\/AAuE7mAZnGB1XXX",
  "displayName": "",
  "description": "",
  "firstName": "",
  "lastName": "",
  "gender": "",
  "language": "",
  "age": "",
  "birthDay": 0,
  "birthMonth": 0,
  "birthYear": 0,
  "email": "fXXX@gmail.com",
  "emailVerified": "",
  "phone": "",
  "address": null,
  "country": "",
  "region": "",
  "city": null,
  "zip": ""
}
```

Isn't every gmail account should have firstName and lastName ?

Comment: If the user hasnt filled out the information google cant return it to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Isn't the first name and last name is mandatory when creating Gmail account?

Comment: nope not as far as i know

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your comment, do you know the way to create a Gmail account without first name and last name?

Comment: I cant tell you that I haven't created a google account in a number of years you might want to try theses could also be legacy accounts created before they started requiring first name and last name to create an account . 
 It could also be an account merged from another email provider. 
 you may want to try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Google only returns the data it has about a user so if the user hasnt filled the information out then the api isnt going to return it.  Also some of this information can be set to private by the user namely birth date, in order for the api to return that data the user must have set their birth date to public in their profile.

The only advice i can give is to add fields=* to your request this should ensure that all of the data that google has is returned.  Some of the Google APIs limit the response and require you to use the fields parameter on the call if you want additional data.